# Does not calculate every row of grid asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having trouble kindly help please. I have a grid, in 1st row of grid values are calculate but in other rows calculation does not make any effect. I used data table at back end. What do i do now?? Help plesae..

---

### Javascript Code

```
            function CalculateTotal() {
            var Gtot = 0;
            var Participation = document.getElementById('txtCl_Part').value-0;
            var Assgnmnt = document.getElementById('txtAssgnmnt').value-0;
            var Quiz = document.getElementById('txtQuiz').value-0;
            var WrPaper = document.getElementById('txtWP').value-0;
            var OSME = document.getElementById('txtOSME').value-0;

            var Total = parseFloat(Participation) + parseFloat(Assgnmnt) + parseFloat(Quiz) + parseFloat(WrPaper) + parseFloat(OSME);
            if (!isNaN(Total)) {
                document.getElementById('txtTotal').value = Total;
            }
            else {
                alert("Nikal");
            }

            var getTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value - 0;
            var Gtot = parseInt(Gtot) + parseFloat(getTotal);
            if (!isNaN(Gtot)) {
                document.getElementById('txtGTot').value = Gtot;
            }

            else {
                alert("Cannot Show Total");
            }

            var Percentage = (parseFloat(Gtot) * 100) / 400;

            if (!isNaN(Percentage)) {
                document.getElementById('txtPercent').value = Percentage;
            }
            else {
                alert("Cannot show percentage");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code-behind too. You are only calculating on the elements that are retrieved using the getElementById method. You need to fill these elements with data from each row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you'd do such calculations clientside, and not serverside where you already have access to all the data to perform the calculations you like? Based upon the results, you can always have a js popup with a message.

Comment: Jean-Paul Mars help me on this, what do i do now on this code?

Comment: Either a seperate query towards your database or in the code behind. Your existing code behind would be handy, though.